# Does the termination policy for an Autoscaling Group also apply for the associated Warm Pool?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-auto-scaling

I have an autoscaling group and an associated warm pool. I'm able to set the termination policy of the autoscaling group to "Newest Instance" but I have noticed that the instances terminated from the warm pool do not necessarily follow the same termination policy for the autoscaling group.

In the documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/ec2-auto-scaling-warm-pools.html), it says it uses the default termination policy and references [this link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/ec2-auto-scaling-termination-policies.html#default-termination-policy) that explains all termination policies.

So it's not clear for me, is it possible to customize the termination policy for the instances being terminated from the warm pool? Do they follow the same one set for the autoscaling group? Or do they always follow the default policy?